# A good way to replace text in a table cell using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a method which is supposed to replace text inside a single XWPFTableCell. I have seen before that the right way to do it looks like this:

```
for (XWPFTable tbl : doc.getTables()) {
   for (XWPFTableRow row : tbl.getRows()) {
      for (XWPFTableCell cell : row.getTableCells()) {
         for (XWPFParagraph p : cell.getParagraphs()) {
            for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
              String text = r.getText(0);
              if (text != null && text.contains("needle")) {
                text = text.replace("needle", "haystack");
                r.setText(text,0);
              }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But these inner loops really blow my mind. So I decided to write pretty much the same method, which looks exactly like this, but for one single cell.

Here it is:

```
private void replaceSimpleText(XWPFTableCell cellToChangeTextIn, String textToReplaceOn) //There must be a better way...
{
    List<XWPFRun> allRunners = cellToChangeTextIn.getParagraphs().get(0).getRuns();

    for (XWPFRun r : allRunners) 
    {
          r.setText("", 0);
    }

    XWPFRun runner = allRunners.get(0);
    String text = runner.getText(0);    
    text = text.replace(text, textToReplaceOn);
    runner.setText(text, 0);

}
```

I know it looks really ugly, but I have not found a better way. First a thought that this method will be okay:

```
private void replaceSimpleText(XWPFTableCell cellToChangeTextIn, String textToReplaceOn) //There must be a better way...
{
    for (XWPFParagraph p : cellToChangeTextIn.getParagraphs()) {
            for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {
              String text = r.getText(0);
              if (text != null) {
                text = text.replace(text, textToReplaceOn);
                r.setText(text,0);
              }
            }
         }
}
```

But unfortunetely if I execute this with the following data:

```
replaceSimpleText(row.getCell(1), "test");
```

It gives me **"testtesttesttesttest"** in a row. It equals to the size of XWPFRun collection(5). Why does it happen? Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your text might be split over several runs, depending on how MS Word felt at the time it did the save...

Comment: If the need is replacing placeholders by text in Word, for ex. put Doe as $SURENAME and John as $GIVENNAME, then best practice is not having the placeholders as text in the Word document but having placeholders as fields in Word document. Read about it:: [Create forms that users complete or print in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-040c5cc1-e309-445b-94ac-542f732c8c8b). Those fields cannot be split into single text runs and so always can be filled properly.